# Mot pour "Rejeter une idée par préjugé avant même de l'avoir correctement considérée"

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Je cherche un mot pour dire :

Rejeter une idée par préjugé, avant même de l'avoir correctement considérée.
Une personne ayant ce comportement serait du genre à dire "Non ça ne marchera jamais, ça ne vaut pas le coup d'essayer", mais sans chercher à apporter de solution.

On peut dire que cette personne fait preuve de '...'

Comment: Danss ce cas très précis, on pourra dire : « cette personne fait preuve de défaitisme. »

Comment: Hum, c'est très proche, mais j'aimerai que ça porte le sens de "ne pas accepter une idée nouvelle sans vraiment la considérer, par ego ou abscence de confiance en la personne la proposant"
[exemple en contexte](https://youtu.be/di37vC4icXg?list=PLNBLxZIFO1N2yb2d5tRly6xYvM7FM2YOM&t=815)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je reprends mon commentaire :

> Dans ce cas très précis, on pourra dire : « cette personne fait preuve de défaitisme. »

On pourrait dire également :

> cette personne fait preuve d'un *a priori* négatif.

ou

> cette personne a une idée préconçue/fait preuve de parti pris

Answer (score 1):

On peut dire que cette personne est *psychorigide*.

Answer (score 1):

Selon les conséquences de de comportement, on pourrait dire que cette personne fait preuve d'**obscurantisme** ou bien qu'elle est **visionnaire**.

Answer (score 0):

Couplé au *défaitisme*, ça me fait aussi penser à une forme d'***obscurantisme***, car c'est carrément la pensée critique qui est rejetée par de telles attitudes.

Comment: Hum.. je précise que j'ai écrit ma réponse avant @mouviciel.. dont la seule contribution est donc "visionnaire" ... non mais je vous jure... aucune gêne..